# regex to check 9 length characters for the prefix

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to create a regex to

valid following type string only

1. first 2 characters 0 to 9
2. next 3 characters 000 to 366 then 501 to 866
3. next 4 characters 0 to 9
4. finally `x` or X

so I did that using following

```
([0-9]{2}(001|002|003|004|005|006|007... |366|501|...|866)[0-9]{4}[x|X]$)
```

so this can validate properly `900033618x`

but this also taking `9001033618x` as valid onces

how to restrict to 9 character length before x or X

I tried do this, like following

```
(^\d[[0-9]{2}(001|002|003|004|005|006|007... |366|501|...|866)[0-9]{4}]{9}[x|X]$)
```

but this not working

Comment: tester i used to check http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: Get rid of the ORs you know the next 2 digits are 00, and then the one after that is  00[1-7].

Comment: @johnny5 no here i mentioned little , I have to check 001 to 210 and then 366 to 400

Comment: where do you mention that? #2. states 000-007, if you have to check for other numbers explicitly then filter out that  result set, if they apply to all the string then that should be included in your numbered ruleset

Comment: That would still be `([01][0-9]{2}|2(0[0-9]|10)|3(6[6-9]|[7-9][0-9])|400)` using character classes

Comment: @johnny5 extremely sorry since I need make this simply, previously i made in that way

Comment: @JamesK as you suggested once i used like this `([01][0-9]{2}|2(0[0-9]|10)|3(6[6-9]|[7-9][0-9])|400)[0-9]{4}[x|X]$)` in here as a sample `900033618x` not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do what you say:

```
^[0-9]{2}(?:[01][0-9][0-9]|[24]00|3(?:6[6-9]|[7-9][0-9]))[0-9]{4}[xX]$
```

Note: watch beginning caret `^`

Comment: Using `\d` shorthand: `^\d{2}(?:[01]\d\d|[24]00|3(?:6[6-9]|[7-9]\d))\d{4}[xX]$`

Comment: how to identity whole word as correct one with 9 number prefix and x or X charachter

Comment: By using provided regex in answer?!

Comment: im trying to get whole string as valid which is 9 numbers and x or X but answer u mention check only prefix not with other criterias

Comment: What could be a sample input?

Comment: 900033618x valid one , 9001033618x invalid one

Comment: okay thanks, i cant understand above one, pardon me if i want to check 001 to 366 and then 501 to 866, not to check (001 to 200 then 366 to 400) how above one change

Comment: You shouldn't change main requirements of your question. However this is what you mean [**`^[0-9]{2}(?!000)(?:[0-2][0-9][0-9]|3([0-5][0-9]|6[0-6])|5(?!00)[0-9][0-9]|[67][0-9][0-9]|8[0-5][0-9]|86[0-6])[0-9]{4}[xX]$`**](https://regex101.com/r/A4AcEU/2)

Comment: yeah im desererve to downvote extremely srry i tried make it simple and accrording to that i suppose to build myself, anyway i unable to figured it out algorithm, many thanks for the answer